# Postgres still connecting via SSL - despite invalid certificates

Tags: postgresql, ssl

I'm playing around with SSL connections to a test postgres server and I'm finding I can still initiate an SSL connection despite invalid certificates. (The valid date has expired)

### I have enforced SSL connections in the pg_hba.conf

```
## pg_hba.conf - SSL TESTING
hostssl         mike            mike            192.168.56.106/32       md5
```

### SSL Certificate is expired:

```
$ openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -dates
notBefore=Feb 22 18:29:39 2019 GMT
notAfter=Feb 23 18:29:39 2019 GMT
```

### Still able to connect via SSL:

```
postgres:/db/postgresql/10/data>psql "sslmode=require host=192.168.56.105 dbname=mike user=mike"
Password: 
psql (10.7)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.
mike=>
```

### Why can I still connect?

I'm hoping for a situation where the connection is rejected because the certificate is invalid - am I missing something? Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html#LIBQ-SSL-CERTIFICATES) says:

> By default, PostgreSQL will not perform any verification of the server certificate.

In other words, SSL is used for encryption.

> […]
>   To allow the client to verify the identity of the server, place a root certificate on the client and a leaf certificate signed by the root certificate on the server.
>   […]
>   Once a chain of trust has been established, there are two ways for the client to validate the leaf certificate sent by the server. If the parameter `sslmode` is set to `verify-ca`, libpq will verify that the server is trustworthy by checking the certificate chain up to the root certificate stored on the client. If `sslmode` is set to `verify-full`, libpq will also verify that the server host name matches the name stored in the server certificate.

Comment: It seems odd to me that you can initiate an SSL connection despite invalid certs (postgres performs no verification). It means we have no reason to maintain the certs if all we are after is encrypted connections and we are not bothered about server verification